# unexpected view in scroll view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

as I'm trying to learn swift in this part I'm learning scroll view.The WHITE color right under the red color(In the circle) is the thing which is not expected to be there. Does anybody know what is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code responsible for that. Also please do not post images as links.

Comment: there is no code behind the UI! I'm making it in storyboard

Comment: stackOverFlow only let me post pic in this way

Comment: The same white appears appears to be there on your storyboard as well. How about investigating that?

Comment: as I scroll down the vc it seems to be part of the navigation controller is that possible?

Comment: I think the problem is glaringly visible in your second screenshot. What have your done to your navigation bar?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri as it is iphone X and I made it a  freeform vc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the TRANSLUCENT  in the navigation controller and it removed the white space! I don't know why but it did.